# Spark - UbuntuVM - insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu-14.04, java

I'm trying to install Spark1.5.1 on Ubuntu14.04 VM. After un-tarring the file, I changed the directory to the extracted folder and executed the command "./bin/pyspark" which should fire up the pyspark shell. But I got an error message as follows:

> **[** OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c5550000, 715849728, 0) failed;
>   error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)  There is insufficient
>   memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>
> Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 715849728 bytes
>   for committing reserved memory.
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   /home/datascience/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/hs_err_pid2750.log **]**

Could anyone please give me some directions to sort out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We need to set `spark.executor.memory` in `conf/spark-defaults.conf` file to a value specific to your machine. For example,

```
usr1@host:~/spark-1.6.1$ cp conf/spark-defaults.conf.template conf/spark-defaults.conf
nano conf/spark-defaults.conf
spark.driver.memory              512m
```

For more information, refer to the official documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much what it says. It wants 7GB of RAM. So give the VM ~ 8GB of RAM.

Comment: I've tried changing the Base Memory in the VM's settings but couldn't do it. Could you please tell me how do I change?

Comment: @Reactormonk I think your off by an order of magnitude :)

Comment: @Preetham Stop VM, changes memory allocation, start again? If you cannot allocate more you can always use swap.

Comment: @zero323 uh-oh. Ok, so only 600MB. I'd still assume the VM doesn't have enough RAM.